# Twitter Bootstrap Grid with 1 Large column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a go at Twitter Bootstrap 3 for the first time and seem to be getting stuck when it comes to the grid system.

I am ok when it comes to using rows but I am trying to achieve a simple layout like the below image..

[image]

I can't even work out how to begin!  Does anybody have a link to a jsfiddle or similar I can have a look at to read up on?

Comment: Use nested grid. If you want to have equal height columns you'll need to add css hack for it (i.E. using flex)

Comment: Are you making this, with equal heights and a black background? Like a Mondrian layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially you create two columns, and in the second column you are creating a new grid to hold your four cells. You can change the `md` in `col-md-6` to break at the resolution you need.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8nppuc0z/)**

Comment: code written here and jsFiddle are different...go check it

Comment: @sanjayduttindia- The only difference is that in my fiddle I used the extra small classes instead of the medium. The structure is identical otherwise.